# Mercurial web interface readable folder names

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I've set up mercurial server and default mercurial web interface. I've set `collapse` option to `true` so I can see folder hierarchy when viewing repositories in web interface. I know that I can set `name`, `description`, `contact` etc. for each repository and all that stuff will be shown in web interface. Is it possible to do the same for the folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer in mercurial sources.

Here you can see than `contact` and `description` fields are always empty for directories:

```
# add '/' to the name to make it obvious that
# the entry is a directory, not a regular repository
row = {'contact': "",
       'contact_sort': "",
       'name': name + '/',
       'name_sort': name,
       'url': url,
       'description': "",
       'description_sort': "",
       'lastchange': d,
       'lastchange_sort': d[1]-d[0],
       'archives': [],
       'isdirectory': True}

seendirs.add(name)
yield row
```

When you try to cheat and create empty `.hg` folder by yourself, mercurial will treat that folder as a mercurial repository and when you try to open this folder in web interface, you'll see repository overview instead of directory listing.

So, I can't do what I want without modifying sources.